# join two sequences in scala

Tags: scala, collections

This is rewritten question. Previous one is unclear.

**1) Introduction**

I need some cool structure, that would **store** my values. I need that my cool structure can **add** items to it, and sometimes I need that my cool structure can **fold** containing elements into something based on passed *foldFunction* . Generally something like `scala.collection.immutable.List` is great, besides point 2.
See this in action:

```
val coolContainer = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: Nil
val folded = coolContainer.foldLeft("")((acc, curr)=> acc + curr)
```

Yea! I got what I wanted - the shiny `"1234"` String :)

**2) Additional requirements**
Then I want that my cool structure can be appended to another one. More over this is very important that such operation must be efficient because my program will mostly do such operations. Because of that, the "appending of two containers" algorithm with complexity **O(1)** is very expected.

So, lets just try to append two Lists, one to another using standard way with the `++` function.

```
val locomotive = (1 to 1000000).toList
val vehicle = (1000000 to 2000000).toList
val train = locomotive ++ vehicle
```

So what is going here? As most of you probably know, the `List` in Scala Standard Library API is implemented as *head* prepended to *tail* where tail is another List. Finally the last element in list is prepended to empty List `Nil`.

This architecture implies that if you join two lists using the `++` function, algoirithm under the hood will traverse `locomotive` through all elements until the last item and then replace the *tail* (which is the `Nil`) with the value of another List - with the `vehicle` in our example. The **complexity is O(size_of_loclomotive)**. Ehh, :/ I want it to be O(1).

Finally the question.

**Is there in scala container, that behaves similarly to the `List` and meets the above requirements?**

---

Deprecated, old question. Just in case if you are just interested how it was reasked and don't.

Basically I want to choose the best pair: structure and method for appending one sequence to another. The efficiency is the **key** in this scenario.

Read below snipped to understand what I want to achieve but more efficient:

```
val seq1 = List(1,2,3)
val seq2 = List(4,5,6)
val seq3 = seq1 ++ seq2   //I am afraid that seq1 and seq2 will be traversed 
                          //what is not the most efficient way to join two seqs
```

Comment: Does it have to be appended to the end? Prepending is O(1) vs O(n) for appending.

Comment: This is very usefull comparision where you can find the proper collection for your needs http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be appending over and over, where eventually the prepended list is going to be much bigger than the appended, your best bet for an immutable data structure is `Vector`.  If the lists are all really short, though, it's hard to beat just plain `List`; yes, you have to allocate three extra objects but the overhead for `Vector` is much more.

Keep in mind, though that you can prepend and reverse (with a `List`), and that there are mutable data structures that support an efficient append (e.g. `ArrayBuffer`, or perhaps `ListBuffer` if you want to convert to a list when you're done appending).

Answer (score 0):

Appending is O(n), for constant time appending you can use a [ListBuffer](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer) and call `toList` when you want the immutable list.